# Split bash command into several reusable pieces

Tags: bash, find

How can I split a command that uses pipes into different pieces?

I have the following working bash command:

```
RESULT=$(find "/path/to/releases" -maxdepth 0 -type d -print0 | xargs -r -0 ls -1 -t | tail -n 1)
```

I would rather have the pipes split up into multiple variables like so, so I can reuse RESULT1 or RESULT2 somewhere else:

```
RESULT1=$(find "/path/to/releases" -maxdepth 0 -type d -print0)

if [ -n ${RESULT1} ]; then
  RESULT2=${RESULT1} | xargs -r -0 ls -1 -t
  RESULT3=${RESULT2} | tail -n 1
]
```

Is this possible?

Update: The reason I also want to split things up is because I want to check first if the first part actually finds something before proceeding to the next pipe.

Update #2: Solved it like this; Used some examples above to make it easier to explain my problem. Here's the actual code.

```
DEPLOY_PATH="/data/www"
KEEP_RELEASES=3
function cleanup() {
      RELEASES=()
      OLDEST_RELEASE=

      for item in "${DEPLOY_PATH}"/releases/* ; do
        [[ -L ${item} || ! -d ${item} ]] && continue
        [[ -z ${OLDEST_RELEASE} || ${item} -ot ${OLDEST_RELEASE} ]] && OLDEST_RELEASE=${item}
        RELEASES+=("${item}")
      done

      if [ "${#RELEASES[@]}" -gt 0 ] && [ "${#RELEASES[@]}" -gt "${KEEP_RELEASES}" ]; then
        rm -rf "${DEPLOY_PATH}"/releases/$(basename "${OLDEST_RELEASE}")
        cleanup
      fi
}
```

To bad that chaining with "find" and pipes likes xargs is not always the best choice. Imo it makes my script bigger when using a regular bash array.

Comment: The output of `find` is a null-separated string, but shell variables are null-terminated; `RESULT1` would only have the first file output by `find`.

Comment: In this case, you don't need `find`: `files=( /path/to/releases/*/ )`

Comment: And once the files are in an array, it's easier to iterate over the with a `for` loop than to use `xargs`.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of reusability, we'd better take an approach similar to this :

```
find_release(){
    find "/path/to/releases" -maxdepth 0 -type d -print0
}

list_by_time(){
    xargs -r -0 ls -1 -t
}

tail_1(){
    tail -n 1
}

# Then you can do :
find_release | list_by_time | tail_1
```

Comment: Thanks Philippe, but using this method I cannot check if find_release actually contains something before proceeding to the next pipe.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, It's possible:

```sh
RESULT1=$(find "/path/to/releases" -maxdepth 0 -type d)
RESULT2=$(echo "$RESULT1" | xargs -r ls -1 -t)
RESULT3=$(echo "$RESULT2" | tail -n 1)
```

Comment: Great thanks a lot. I do however get a warning "command substitution: ignored null byte in input". Any chance to also supress or solve this too?

Comment: This will not work for the given case; `RESULT1` cannot store multiple null-terminated file names.

Comment: Thanks @chepner, I've edited the answer to remove the `-print0` and `-0`, it should works now.

Comment: And now it won't work for files that contain whitespace in their names. There's a reason why `-print0` gets used.